# Sub Menu's are not coming under main menu

Tags: commerce

I am using this code to fetch menu's in drupal. I have given Home as parent menu and other are sub menu's like submenu1, submenu2 etc. But in front end they are not coming under Home menu. Only Home menu appear on front end.

```
<?php if ($main_menu): ?>
     <?php
          // This code snippet is hard to modify. We recommend turning off the
          // "Main menu" on your sub-theme's settings form, deleting this PHP
          // code block, and, instead, using the "Menu block" module.
          // @see https://drupal.org/project/menu_block
          print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
            'links' => $main_menu,
            'attributes' => array(
              'id'=>'s5_nav',
              'class' => array('menu'),
            ),

          )); 
          ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nice Menus](https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus) to solve your issue.